# Drupal 7 how can I alter page content generated with module?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I have one module:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['mymodule'] = array(
      'title' => t('My Module'),
      'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_view',
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
      'page arguments' => array(1),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );

    return $items;
}
function MYMODULE_view() {
   return array(
        '#theme' => 'my_module_theme',
        '#variable' => 'some variable'
    );
}
```

In the other module I want to alter this content to change the theme and add some variables. How can I do it?

Comment: I think there is no need to use 'page arguments' => array(1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the variables of the page content implementing the [template_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) function in your module or theme. As of Clive's comment, I want to update that you can preferably use [hook_page_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7), which is called earlier than preprocess function.

```
function YOURMODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Do your changes here
  // If have Devel module installed
  // You can use dpm() function to print the contents of $variables array. 
  // dpm($variables)
}
```

or

```
function YOURMODULE_page_alter(&$page) {
  // Do your changes here
  // If have Devel module installed
  // You can use dpm() function to print the contents of $variables array. 
  // dpm($page)
}
```

Additional Reference:

- [Render Arrays in Drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/930760) See the section "Creating Content As Render Array"

> A page callback should return a render array, as should hook_block_view()'s $block['content']. This allows your module and other modules to treat the content as data for as long as possible in the page generation process.

Comment: Perfectly valid, but personally I'd prefer [`hook_page_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7), where you still have the page content as a render array

Comment: hook_preprocess_page() contains my data rather hook_page_alter() does not

Comment: It's definitely there, you just need to find it on the nested arrays

Comment: hook_page_alter() does not always work. The render array that's returned from a custom page callback like in OP's example is NOT available in hook_page_alter(). It is only available in the hook_preprocess_page(). I followed the rendering code with XDebug and confirmed this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [module_load_include($type, $module, $name = NULL)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) to include other module;s content.

> $type: The include file's type (file extension).
>
> $module: The module to which the include file belongs.
>
> $name: (optional) The base file name (without the $type extension). If
>   omitted, $module is used; i.e., resulting in "$module.$type" by
>   default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter your menu link item you can use hook_menu_alter(&$items) function and change your 'page callback' with it. E.g:

```
function myAnotherModule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['mymodule']['page callback'] = 'MYMODULE_another_view';
}

function MYMODULE_another_view() {
  return array(
    '#theme' => 'my_module_another_theme',
    '#variable' => 'some variable'
  );
}
```

p.s// Don't forget to flush your cache after implementing the hook

Comment: The OP is asking to alter the page content, not to change the page callback. They are not the same.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. MYMODULE_view() is not an alterable function. You can alter 'mymodule' page callback or 'my_module_theme' with hook_theme_registry_alter. Do you have any solution to the OP's question?

Comment: The function returns a render array, thus it is alterable, and yes I have an answer.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. Interesting solution.. I don't have much experience with template_preprocess_page() function (because I don't like to work with theme layer functions). Can you explain how you alter the theme and variables of MYMODULE_view(), please (this would be useful)? Thanks for advance.

Comment: I have added an additional reference to my answer.